# push to object if not exists from params

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I've been trying and searching how to loop through the params to check if those already exist in an array, i haven't got it fully working but when there is a duplicate value it dose not return at all.

The idear is pass multiple values is param then loop through those vals and only push if it dose not exist in the array.

```
var arr = [7,3,1];

function pushNew(obj) {
var prams = obj;

 for(var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++){

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == prams[k]) {
     return;
   }
 }
  array.push(prams[k]);
}
// console.info(arr);

}


  pushNew([2,7,4]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your existing code *nearly* works.

You can set a flag if you find a match in the inner loop and instead of *return* you should use *break* to escape the loop. Then use *push* after the inner loop if a match wasn't found. Also, there is no need for both *obj* and *prams* (which I've renamed to *params*), so:

```js
var arr = [7,3,1];

function pushNew(params) {
  var found;

  for(var k=0; k<params.length; k++){
    
    // Set found to initial value on each outer loop
    found = false;

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

      // If find match, set flag and break from loop (for efficiency)
      if (arr[i] == params[k]) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    // If match not found, push into arr
    if (!found) arr.push(params[k]); 

  }
}

pushNew([7,2])

document.write(arr); // 7,3,1,2
```

If you want efficient code, consider creating an index and using *in*:

```js
 var arr = [7,3,1];

function addParams(params) {
  var index = arr.reduce(function(acc, v) {
    acc[v] = true;
    return acc;
  },{});
  params.forEach(function(v) {
    if (!(v in index)) arr.push(v);
  });
}

addParams([7,3,2]);

document.write(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

A short and more modern way to just get all the unique values is to use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). A `Set` is an array-like structure that will only hold unique values. `Array.from` converts an array-like structure into a real array.

In your case, you can just concat both arrays, pass them to `Set` to remove the duplicates, and use `Array.from` to convert it back to a regular array.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var result = Array.from(new Set(arr1.concat(arr2)));

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: learnt some thing new.This is better way. Thanks you. Is it possible for you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @user2181397 Added snippet to answer.

Comment: @user2181397—it depends on your criteria for "better". If you want efficient, then likely it is faster to create an index of the properties of *arr* the first time through, then just use the *in* operator after that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` to validate if element is present in an array. `forEach` is another array method which works like loop.

```
var arr = [7,3,1];

function pushNew(obj) {
//var prams = obj;
  obj.forEach(function(item){   // iterate through each element
   if(arr.indexOf(item) == -1){ //indexOf return -1 is element is not present in an array
     arr.push(item)
     }
  })

console.log(arr);
}
pushNew([2,7,4]);
```

Working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/4kbzsgoz/)

Comment: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not working in IE8 or lower

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [7, 3, 1];

function pushNew(obj) {
    for (var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++) {
        if (arr.indexOf(obj[k]) == -1) {
            arr.push(obj[k]);
        }
    }
}

pushNew([2, 7, 4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.union function of lodash.

_.union([2, 1], [4, 2], [1, 2]);
// → [2, 1, 4]